# How to return in out parameter from procedure using groovy

Tags: sql, groovy

I follow this example to call and return parameter from procedure using groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features

in section Stored procedure support there no example how to call in out procedure
I try this but output is still null

```
sql.call(GString.EMPTY +  "{call " + schema + "." + name + "($par1,$par2)}"){ output ->  println output }
```

UPDATE:

in my case if par1 == null then it take new entry (this is reason of "in our parameter" ) so I created something like this:

```
    if (par1 == null) {
        sql.call(GString.EMPTY +  "{call " + schema + "." + name + "(${Sql.VARCHAR},$par2)}"){  output_par1 -> println "par1: " + output_par1  }
    } else {
        sql.call(GString.EMPTY +  "{call " + schema + "." + name + "($par1,$par2)}"){}
        println "par1: " + par1
    }
```

so If par1 is null procedure generates new value and then is println and if par1 is not null then just println it. This works for me but if someone want to return in out parameter which is not null then I still dont know how to write it.

UPDATE

really nothing ? after 7 days with bounty ? I should probably add more point

Comment: println output return null

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: eh I am not sure what you want to hear. Can you give me some option? Database is Oracle

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995362/cant-call-pl-sql-stored-procedure-with-out-parameter-oracletypes-cursor

Comment: I'm sure you have already tried placing println "par1: " + par1 inside the closure just like the call in the if block. If not, try that. If that doesn't work, try something like par1 = call myprocedure(par1, par2).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is elsewhere.
You have a syntax error here:

```
sql.call(GString.EMPTY +  "{call " + schema + "." + name + "($par1,$par2)}")
```

The call inside the string will be never fulfilled, because you have no $ before {. On the contrary, your parameters DO have senseless $ before them.

```
sql.call(GString.EMPTY +  "${call " + schema + "." + name + "(par1,par2)}")
```

is correct.

The same with other code lines.